# Is there any way to do this in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I want a code that will return a `list` like this :

```
def list = ["RR","SS"]
//code to get the output as [R,R,S,S]
```

I came up with idea like this:

```
def Ash = ["RR","as","RTY"]
def listA = []
for(i=0;i<Ash.size();i++)
{ 
    listA <<  Ash[i].collect{ it as String }
}
AshNew = listA.flatten()
println AshNew // this prints [R, R, a, s, R, T, Y] which is what i needed..
```

But still i want to know that whether we can do this similar stuff in Groovy by using another way? Since I'm a novice in Groovy i want to know more **Groovier** solution! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
Ash.join().split("").tail()
```

Comment: this prints like this `[, S, R, P, P]` it would be good if the first `,` in the list have been omitted!

Comment: fixed this, ommited the first element

Comment: Thanks good work! i guess i still need to be much groovier after seeing your solution :D

Comment: how this works? first if i give `Ash.join()` it returns `SRPP` now how does you applying `split` method on this `SRPP` by passing argument as `""`? Here is no way i can see "" between `SRPP`

Comment: `.split` gets a regexp. The regexp `""` matches every gap between every character. However, it is a little bit weird that the gap between `P` and `\n` gets omitted :(

Answer (score 4):

Is

```
AshNew = Ash.collect { it as List }.flatten()
```

any better?

Comment: Oh `collect` does the job of iteration thorough all elements right! God i have forgotten that totally! :D

Comment: The spread operator does collect: Ash*.asType(List).flatten()

Comment: My version is certainly denser.  I added another answer with even simpler syntax

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Ash.join().findAll()
```

findAll returns each element which isn't null, which for a joined string is all of them.

Comment: +1 for a nice clean alternative.  Could also use `Ash.join().toList()` which might be a bit more opaque in its workings